# How to make loop printing in a horizontal way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to print **prime numbers** in the **horizontal way**, but it is displaying vertically....can any one suggest on this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#  This program is to find the prime numbers in the given range

x = input ('Please enter the start range number: ')
y = input ('Please enter the end range number: ')

#  validating the start range value should be greater than the end range value
if x < y:
    for num in range(x, y):
#       validating the start range value greater than 1
        if num < 1:
            print 'Please enter Starting numeric value more than 1' 
            break
        elif num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                print (str(num) + ",")
else:
    print 'Please enter Start Range Number value more than one'
    print 'Start Range Number should be lesser than End Range Number value'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `end` parameter in the `print` function.

the `end` in `print()` function is set default to '\n', so you can use

`print(str(num), end=', ')`

to make this you code work as you expected

Comment: While giving print (str(num), end=", ")  gives syntax error at =

Comment: Make sure that you are using Python3, this answer is for Python3.x. `print` is a function in Python3 rather than a statemnt in Python2.x